# When is $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$ dense in $L^p(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}$, $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $1\leq p<\infty$.

What are the (most common) sufficient conditions (if such conditions exists) that we can impose on $\Omega$, $m$ and $p$ to get
(1) $C_0^\infty(\Omega)$ dense in $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$?
(2) $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$ dense in $L^p(\Omega)$?
(3) $W^{m,p}_0(\Omega)$ dense in $L^p(\Omega)$ ?

What are the most important cases? What is the answer if we replace $\Omega$ by $\overline{\Omega}$?

Thanks.

Comment: http://people.bath.ac.uk/masgrb/Sobolev/notes.pdf check this. I think it has all the embedding theorem you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1): Only if $m=0$. Otherwise, the closure of $C_0^\infty(\Omega)$ in $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$ is
$W^{m,p}_0(\Omega)$, a genuine subset of $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$.

(2): Always true. Even $C^\infty_0(\Omega)$, with bound $L^p$-norm is dense in $L^p(\Omega)$.

(3): Always true - see the answer for (2).